# Galton Box; Printing a histogram

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Hey guys I'm writing a program for homework to display the path of a ball in a Galton box

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltypc.png]

My program so far picks how many balls you want to drop, and the amount of slots at the bottom of the box, and the shows you the random path the ball takes.

The problem I've run into is creating a histogram that depicts the end result.
One important piece of information that I found out, is that every time the ball falls to the right, it moves over one position. So if the print statement is LRLRLR it would be in the 3rd slot because of the 3 R's.

An example of a random histogram it could print:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCotG.png]

```
public class Set_8_P6_21 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declaring variables and calling scanner
    int balls, slots;

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of balls to drop: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    balls = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of slots: ");
    slots = input.nextInt();


    char[] arrayslot = new char[slots-1];
    int[] arraypattern = new int[slots-1];

    // Nested loop that runs the amount of balls through the machine, and through the amount of slots. 
    for (int i = 0; i < balls; i++) {
        System.out.println();

        for (int j = 0; j < slots-1; j++) {

            double k = Math.random();

            if (k < 0.5) {
                arrayslot[j] = 'L' ;
                arraypattern[j] = 1; // This is where I am trying to make my histogram
            }

            else if (k >= 0.5) {
                arrayslot[j] = 'R';
                arraypattern[j] = 0; // This is where I am trying to make my histogram
            }

            System.out.print(arrayslot[j]);

        }

    }}}
```

If anyone has an idea of how could make this print with the information coming from the loop it would be very helpful, thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: I'm unsure: aren't you trying to calculate which slot the ball falls into at the end?

Comment: Yeah, so far you run it and it prints this:
http://i.gyazo.com/179aead791363ce3faa9fe498604d123.png

but I can't figure out how to print the 0's to make a histogram out of it. (Basically a picture showing where the balls fell)

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no real need for you to keep the array `arrayslot`, because you print the array element right away, and you don't do anything with it afterwards. So you can just print the character:

```
            if ( k < 0.5 ) {
                System.out.print("L");
            } else {
                System.out.print("R");
            }
```

As you notice, there is also no need for an `else if`. Either k is less than 0.5, or it is greater than it. So you can just use `else`.

In order to figure out which slot the ball will fall into, you need to count the `R`s. To do so, you simply have an `int` that gets 0 at the beginning of each ball's simulation, and then you add to it when you roll an "R" above. So your loop expands to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < balls; i++) {
        int ballSlot = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < slots - 1; j++) {

            double k = Math.random();

            if ( k < 0.5 ) {
                System.out.print("L");
            } else {
                System.out.print("R");
                ballSlot++; 
            }

        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

But of course, if we just do that, the value doesn't go anywhere and we lose it after we finish simulating the ball. What you want to do is keep an array which keeps the number of times we hit each slot. So at the end of each ball's simulation, when we know which slot it fell into, we add 1 to the given slot. If we hit the same slot 3 times, we'll have 3 in that spot in the array:

```
    int[] frequencies = new int[slots];

    // Nested loop that runs the amount of balls through the machine, and
    // through the amount of slots.
    for (int i = 0; i < balls; i++) {
        int ballSlot = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < slots - 1; j++) {

            double k = Math.random();

            if ( k < 0.5 ) {
                System.out.print("L");
            } else {
                System.out.print("R");
                ballSlot++; 
            }

        }

        frequencies[ballSlot]++;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Now, in order to print the histogram properly, you have to start from the tallest column, and work your way down until you reach the "floor" of the histogram, printing an `O` for every slot that has balls at that frequency. For example, if we have 3 balls in slots 4 and 5, and 1 ball in slot 2, you start from 3, the highest frequency:

- For frequency 3, print `O` in the 4th and 5th positions.
- For frequency 2, no new positions at this height, but you have to print `O` in 4th and 5th again, because otherwise you'll have an `O` only at the top of the column, instead of its whole height.
- For frequency 1, you print `O` in the 2nd, 4th and 5th positions.

So in order to do this, we have to find out which is the highest frequency first. You can scan the array for that, but actually, you could calculate it while doing the simulations already:

```
    int[] frequencies = new int[slots];
    int maxFrequency = 0;

    // Nested loop that runs the amount of balls through the machine, and
    // through the amount of slots.
    for (int i = 0; i < balls; i++) {
        int ballSlot = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < slots - 1; j++) {

            double k = Math.random();

            if ( k < 0.5 ) {
                System.out.print("L");
            } else {
                System.out.print("R");
                ballSlot++; 
            }

        }

        frequencies[ballSlot]++;
        if ( frequencies[ballSlot] > maxFrequency ) {
            maxFrequency = frequencies[ballSlot];
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

As you can see, if any frequency is greater than what we have currently as `maxFrequency`, we keep it as our new `maxFrequency`.

Now, the printing of the histogram:

```
    for ( int i = maxFrequency; i > 0; i-- ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < slots; j++ ) {
            if ( frequencies[j] >= i ) {
                System.out.print( "O");
            } else {
                System.out.print( " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

For each position where we don't have a ball at this level, we print a space. For a position where we have a ball, we print an `O`.

The variable `i` represents the current *level* or *height* of the histogram we are drawing. So the condition `if ( frequencies[j] >= i )` means *If at this position, we have at least as many balls as the current height*.

That's it. Add a `System.out.println()` before the simulation loop and before the histogram loop to space between the input, the simulation and the histogram, and you are done.